# git merge changes from another repo

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have inherited some really sloppy code so I created a new repo and ran PHP_Beautifier and php-cs-fixer on the majority of the code. All the while my colleagues have been making their own changes to our existing repo. Now I need to merge those two repos together.

The issue I'm running into is the massive changes to the source files running those two tools has caused. I stepped through them trying to rebase the original repo into my new one but reached the point where it said there were no more conflicts. Yet, git rebase --continue did nothing more, stating:

```
git rebase --continue
Applying: fixed minor typo
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

I apologize if this is a duplicate question but I've tried various methods mentioned in related posts and nothing has worked. I'm lost with what approach to take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that since resolving the conflicts, Git found no differences from what you had before. It's safe to simply skip this rebase step.

```
git rebase --skip
```

Comment: Ok I finally got it all merged in and everything. Now I'm in a detached head. What do I need to do and to which repository or branch should I do it?

Comment: How are you in a detached HEAD? If you are rebasing, then the end result should be a rebased branch, not a deteched HEAD. It sounds to me like you are not done rebasing. Can you show the output of `git status` please?

Comment: `git status   On branch pretty
    nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: Git is reporting "On branch pretty" as a result of a `git status` command, therefore you are not in a detached HEAD state. It looks like you are all done.

Comment: I must have resolved it without realizing it. Thanks so much for your help!